# The same output for all graphics objects

Tags: c#, graphics, bitmap, printdocument

I have several outputs for my datas and want to create one fill-Object for any output-possibility. For example PrintDocument and Bitmap. Thats works with Graphics-Object, but the result is different.

My test method for fill graphics:

```
    protected void fillGraphics(Graphics g)
    {
        g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 3);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, 100, 100, 300, 300);
        g.DrawString("Wichtig!", new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 16), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 120, 120);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Unit of measure of your _drawing context_ isn't the same when you're drawing into a bitmap, a screen context and a printing context. Check it in your Graphics object and convert 100 and 300 to proper values (what you're assuming they are? pixels? tenth of inch?)

Comment: Pixel. So i do add g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel; to determine the unit. Do that property not work for all measures in that Graphics?

Comment: I'd suggest to convert _your_ values to existing unit. Other parameters will be given in another format (for example page margins and size and you have to honor them).